# Decode AngularJS URLs that return "Error: URI Too Long"

Tags: angularjs

Certain old angularjs versions like 1.5.11 suffer from an issue where their error URLs can get too long. These URLs are too long even for the `errors.angularjs.org` server.

Error messages that may appear:

- "Error: URI Too Long"
- "I/O error"
- "Header overflow"

Links:

- [Issue #14744 "Get rid of huge error messages"](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14744)

Comment: Note: upgrading is not an option for me. I'm maintaining a large legacy codebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three routes:

1. Upgrade to 1.6.3 and use errorHandlingConfig

   The [angular.errorHandlingConfig](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.3/docs/api/ng/function/angular.errorHandlingConfig) function was added in 1.6.3, and it lets you specify `objectMaxDepth`.

   However, this will truncate errors, which isn't great. The root cause of an error is typically mentioned last, which is the part that gets truncated.
2. Upgrade to 1.6.10

   [Version 1.6.10](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1610-crystalline-persuasion-2018-04-17) strips error urls from errors, in commit [980b69](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/980b69dcae73dd8a3d0b9d91b63fa7711cd0ba36). This reduces the length of the error.
3. Use AngularJS Error Decoder

   [AngularJS Error Decoder](https://matts-apps.com/angularjs-error-decoder/) is a web page I created specifically for decoding these Angular errors. It's snappy and can handle huge URLs. Feel free to bookmark it.